# Filter boto instance list by 'tag: component': 'foo', or 'tag:component': 'bar'

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I'd like to get a list of instances in boto either have a "component" tag of foo or bar.

Is there a way to avoid making two requests and munging the objects?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should find all instances that have a tag called `component` with a value of either `foo` or `bar`:

```
import boto.ec2
c = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
reservations = c.get_all_instances(filters={'tag:component':['foo', 'bar']})
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I get an empty list. I guess this does &&, no?

Comment: The docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html) say this should do an OR.  Let me try to test a bit more.

Comment: I just tried adding a ``component:foo`` tag to a single instance and then did the above call and it returned the instance.  So, it appears to be doing OR for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
# With boto3
def get_instances_by_tag_value( tag, value):

   ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

   instances = ec2.instances.filter(
       Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:' + tag, 'Values': [value]}])

   for instance in instances:
      print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)

get_instances_by_tag_value('tagname', 'tagvalue') # call function
```