# Filtering ec2-instances with boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I use tags to keep track of my EC2 instances, such as (Project, Environment). I have a use case where I need to filter only those instances that belong to a specific project and to a specific environment.

When I use filter with boto and pass these two values I get a result that does a OR rather than a AND of the filters and so I am receiving a list of instances that belong to different projects but same environment.

Now I can use two lists and then compare the instances in each and get the desired set of instances, but is there a better way of getting this done?

Here is what i am doing:

```
conn = ec2.EC2Connection('us-east-1',aws_access_key_id='XXX',aws_secret_access_key='YYY')
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(filters={"tag-key":"project","tag-value":<project-name>,"tag-key":"env","tag-value":<env-name>})
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
```

Now the instance list that I am getting gives all the instances from the specified project irrespective of the environment and all the instances from the specified environment irrespective of the project.

Comment: this also explains a lot:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361615/filter-boto-instance-list-by-tag-component-foo-or-tagcomponent-bar

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `tag:key=value` syntax to do an AND search on your filters.

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1',aws_access_key_id='xx', aws_secret_access_key='xx')
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(filters={"tag:Name" : "myName", "tag:Project" : "B"})
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
print instances
```

See EC2 API for details
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html

The problem with the syntax you used is that a Python dict has unique keys, so the second `tag-key` entry overwrites the first one :-(

Seb

Comment: But you can have a list of values for one key in the dictionary.

Comment: @garnaat - According to the [EC2 API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html), "You can specify multiple values for a filter. The response includes information for an instance only if it matches at least one of the filter values that you specified." So it looks like having multiple values for one key will match items that fit _any_ of the values, not all of them at once (like I believe the OP wants).

Comment: @garnaat - Oh, never mind. I believe you [already know that to be the case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361769/877069). :)

Comment: Can I use this to exclude tags? What if I want instances that don't have the tag Xyz?

Answer (score 0):

While the [documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html) does not specifically say what happens with multiple filters, the ORing may be by design. In this case, pass the required attributes in sequence to the function and pass in the result of the previous invocation into the next one (using the instance_ids parameter). This will restrict the results in each step with the additional filter. The attributes are then applied in sequence returning the ANDed result you desire.