# Automating EC2 creation using Python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subprocess

I'm trying to automate creating Windows images on EC2 using a Python script and Windows Task Scheduler. So far I have this as my working baseline code.

```
awsstring1 = 'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-49a0a7b3 --name "Node.Js.ServerTest " --output text  --description "Node.Js.ServerTest" --no-reboot'
subprocess.call(awsstring1)
```

Now I want to attach a date and time to the description and name as the additional information. See below

```
datestring = time.strftime("%c")
awsstring1 = 'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-49a0a7b3 --name "Node.Js.ServerTest %s" --output text  --description "Node.Js.ServerTest %s" --no-reboot' %(datestring, datestring))
subprocess.call(awsstring1)
```

Now the code runs with no errors, but it doesn't create the image. Is it because of the way I created the `awsstring1`? If so, is there a work around to this?

Also, is there a way to obtain the output after running a `subprocess.call` command? For example, I want to capture the output of

```
subprocess.call('ls -a')
```

Edit:
When running the code below it is supposed to have an output of the created image.

```
 awsstring1 = 'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-9bedb4b4 --name "rwong_TestInstance" --output text  --description "rwong_TestInstance" --no-reboot' 
 subprocess.call(awsstring1)
```

Output:

```
 {
   "ImageId": "ami-5731123e"
 }
```

I need that ami-5731123e part. If there is a way to send it to a text file that would be great. Obtaining the output will also help me later when I need to run a similar command to obtain the IP address.

Edit2: I have written this code for saving the output to a text file but I am getting an error of "returned non-zero exit status 255" This command without the beginning ' and end ' will work on the command line. Is there a guide on how to format strings like this to be execute using subprocess.check_call?

```
test = 'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-563b6379 --name "rwong_TestInstance" --output text  --description "rwong_TestInstance" --no-reboot'
test2 = r' > "V:\rwong\Work Files\Python\test.txt"' 
subprocess.check_call(test + test2)
```

Comment: You mention you are doing this via "Windows Task Scheduler", but then give an example of running `ls -a` which is not a windows command. Are you doing this on windows platform or not?

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. I changed the post above to reflect on my goal with running subprocess.call.

Comment: You definitely cannot do file redirections without using the unsafe `shell=True`.

Comment: So it looks like a dead end no matter where I go?

Comment: If you use `check_output` like I mention in my answer below, you can capture the output to a string and then use python to write it to a file using standard io functions.

Comment: One other suggestion would be to use the wonderful library [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) instead of trying to write this yourself.

Comment: Yes I was looking into that (link provided) but it isn't what I necessarily need. The checking what instances are running also includes the ones are are stopped so it is hard to figure out which ones I spawned. By extracting the AMI information once I create the image I can also follow the instance ID from the AMI.
Link: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ec2_tut.html

Comment: Boto already supports all of the filters that aws provides. One of those filters is running state, so you can certainly exclude stopped instances.

Comment: If you look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html, you'll see that you want either `instance-state-code` or `instance-state-name` for your filter. Then you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361769/1307166) to apply the filter in boto.

Comment: take a look at this http://aameer.github.io/cloud-computing-101/. you can use ami of your choice. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [docs for `subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), you'll see that you must pass multiple arguments as a `list`, not as a string to `subprocess.call`.

This means that you should do the following instead:

```
awsstring1 = 'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-49a0a7b3 --name "Node.Js.ServerTest" --output text --description "Node.Js.ServerTest" --no-reboot'
subprocess.call(awsstring1.split())
```

Note this assumes that you want to split arguments by whitespace which is how the shell works by default. Alternatively, you can force `subprocess.call` to use the shell by passing `shell=True` as a keyword argument. The default is `False`. However, this is insecure as it opens you up to shell injection attacks.

Also, to get things working without using the shell, you will probably need to remove your inner double quotes unless you want those passed literally on to the `aws` command, which I doubt.

Furthermore, I would use [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) instead of `subprocess.call` to verify that the command is running successfully and not reporting an error code.

In general, to debug these types of issues, you should `print` the full command immediately before executing it. Then try to execute it by hand on the command line. If executing it by hand didn't work, you need to fix the command. If executing it by hand does work, then it is probably user or environment related. Make sure that you are running as the same user in both cases. You can also print out your current environment variables by using the `env` command. Then use `diff` to compare them. Another possibility is differences between shell escapes on the prompt or not, which is why I mentioned the double quotes earlier.

Lastly, to answer your question about capturing output: [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) will do what you want.

Comment: Ok, I will try that with subprocess.check_call. If still doesn't work it won't be a big deal. I also edited my post to answer your question below.

Comment: @RobertWong: On Windows, you can pass the command as a string (it is a native interface). `.split()` is incorrect here (it splits a single quoted argument if there is a space in it). On Unix, `shlex.split(awstring)` may show how the list should look like (though there are edge cases -- you should adjust the list yourself).